# Refining a Sqlite query

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am struggling to find a solution to a problem I have and will appreciate any help - 

I am working on an android app and part of it needs to collect the user clicks

I store every click in a sqlite table with the following parameters - 

click id, click day, click month, click year and click hour

(The date breakdown is for other queries)

**My Task -** 

I need to display a time division of the daily user clicks (from the point he asked and 24 
hours back) by the following time division

morning any hour between 8-11, noon any hour between 12-17, evening any hour between 17-22

night any hour between 22-8 (thats 8 in the morning of the day after)

**My Problem -** 

As for now my query unites the time sections in between two days that is - 

In case I am looking 24 hours back from 5pm and there is a record with an hour 6pm on 
the day before - it counts as today (and it shouldn't be since I want to seperate)

between time slices between two different days **UNLESS** its the **night**

time slice.

**My sql query**

```
SELECT (CASE 
WHEN (click_history_hour > '07:59:59' AND click_history_hour < '12:00:00') THEN '8 - 11' 
WHEN (click_history_hour > '11:59:59' AND click_history_hour < '17:00:00') THEN '12 - 17' 
WHEN (click_history_hour > '16:59:59' AND click_history_hour < '22:00:00') THEN '17 - 22' 
WHEN ((click_history_hour > '21:59:59' AND click_history_hour < '23:59:59') OR (click_history_hour > '00:00:00' AND click_history_hour < '08:00:00')) THEN '22 - 8'
END) 
AS time, COUNT(*) AS quantity 
FROM click_history 
WHERE (click_history_day='25' AND click_history_month='04' AND click_history_year='2014' AND click_history_hour>'00:45:21') 
OR (click_history_day='26' AND click_history_month='04' AND click_history_year='2014') 
GROUP BY (CASE 
WHEN (click_history_hour > '07:59:59' AND click_history_hour < '12:00:00') THEN '8 - 11' 
WHEN (click_history_hour > '11:59:59' AND click_history_hour < '17:00:00') THEN '12 - 17' 
WHEN (click_history_hour > '16:59:59' AND click_history_hour < '22:00:00') THEN '17 - 22' 
WHEN ((click_history_hour > '21:59:59' AND click_history_hour < '23:59:59') OR (click_history_hour > '00:00:00' AND click_history_hour < '08:00:00')) THEN '22 - 8'
END) 
ORDER BY (click_history_month || click_history_day || click_history_year), click_history_hour ASC;
```

Please note - the dates are since this is an actual query from a debug session

any help?

**Edit**

The test data I am checking as for now - 
[image]

The query result -

[image]

Comment: Can you give the table definition - it is unclear if `click_history_hour` is a string or a datetime, and same for other columns.

Comment: all of the columns are varchar, sorry for my typo I wrote data and ment to DATE when date is in the form of dd/mm/yyyy (as I wrote I save every part of the date in a different column)

Comment: You shouldn't store numbers (or dates or times) as varchars. It just makes it difficult to work with them - as you are now finding. OTHER NOTES:: Your SQL statement should have `GROUP BY time` not `GROUP BY (CASE...` .You can't `ORDER BY` columns you aren't selecting. Also, why would you want to order by month, day year?

Comment: My apologies, I realize this is SQLite which doesn't have a timestamp datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
select 
  CASE 
    WHEN click_hour < '09' THEN '23 -  8'
    WHEN click_hour < '12' THEN ' 8 - 11'
    WHEN click_hour < '18' THEN '12 - 17'
    WHEN click_hour < '23' THEN '18 - 22'
    ELSE                        '23 -  8'
  END AS time, 
  COUNT(*) AS quantity 
from 
  (
  SELECT 
    click_history_year||'-'||click_history_month||'-'||click_history_day||' '||click_history_hour  as click_time, 
    substr(click_history_hour,1,2) as click_hour
  FROM click_history
  ) as click_history2
WHERE datetime('now','-1 day') <= click_time
group by time
;
```

Note that this would be even cleaner if you just used a single column to store the timestamp (which I artificially created as `click_time`). You would also eliminate the 4 columns you have now. To get the hour from the timestamp, use `strftime(click_time, '%H')`.

Also, I adjusted the time ranges and comparisons, because some seemed wrong. Perhaps I just misunderstand your requirement.

And note that you could move the `WHERE` clause up into the sub-query (and eliminate `click_time`), but it depends upon how are going to use the code. It would be like this:

```
select 
  CASE 
    WHEN click_hour < '09' THEN '23 -  8'
    WHEN click_hour < '12' THEN ' 8 - 11'
    WHEN click_hour < '18' THEN '12 - 17'
    WHEN click_hour < '23' THEN '18 - 22'
    ELSE                        '23 -  8'
  END AS time, 
  COUNT(*) AS quantity 
from 
  (
  SELECT 
    substr(click_history_hour,1,2) as click_hour
  FROM click_history
  WHERE datetime('now','-1 day') <= click_history_year||'-'||click_history_month||'-'||click_history_day||' '||click_history_hour
  ) as click_history2
group by time
;
```

Here is an SQLfiddle to check the syntax: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/992ca/2

Comment: Hi @Turophile I added some visual image of running your query on a test data table I did in a sqlite browser, as you can see that didnt solve my problem...the 27/04/2014 11:45 and the 28/04/2014 11:20 are count as the same (the returned result set have 4 sections while it need to have 5)

Comment: I can't see your images as imgur is blocked at my site. In any case, the original question was just splitting it into groups, but it sounds from your comment that you want the split to be for each day, then time bracket within each day. Please confirm and I will revise the fiddle.

Comment: That's correct however there is a time division lapping between every two days (the 23-8 section as it starts from one day and slides to the next day), also in what you have sent me (and the same goes for what I posted) the agrregation for every two hours (in deiffrent days though) is joined and being counted as the same time section when it should be counted as two different parts.

I hope you understood me, really appreciate you help btw.